# How to set a Git serverA and another Git serverB are synchronous?

Tags: git

How to set a Git serverA and another Git serverB are synchronous?
I need set 2 Git servers one is normal operation the anothers is backup. 
User can git clone serverA or serverB because their repository are the same.

or another backup git server method?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495558/git-having-2-push-pull-repos-in-sync-or-1-push-pull-and-1-pull-in-sync

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a post-commit script on Server A that will push all the changes to Server B.

Comment: You almost certainly mean `post-update`, since server A's repo will be pushed into, not committed directly to.

Comment: Also, this approach will only work if serverB is never pushed into by developers; if it is, you can have merge conflicts between the two repos and you won't be able to keep them in sync until a human resolves the conflicts. See the related question I linked in a comment to the question.